# MJPEG stream header file

Tags: image, http, video, stream, mjpeg

I'm trying to extract some information from an MJPEG stream that is being transmitted wirelessly through HTTP protocol.  I am most interested in the time stamp at which the received images were captured.  Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?

(Note: I am using MJPG-streamer to stream the images to the PC)

Comment: maybe run ffprobe on it?